# Floyd-Warshall algorithm visualization: length is known but predecessors aren't

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to visualize Floyd-Warshall algorithm. The problem is when it finds path length, it's not neccessary that there will be predecessors ready to build this path at the moment of finding, so I can't actually display the path though distance is already known. Let me explain on the example from Wikipedia:

Here's the adjacency matrix of original graph:

[image: original adjacency matrix]

If we look at 3rd row, we see there's two infinities beside each other. Let's jump to the beginning of 3rd iteration (or *k*).

[image: distances at 3rd iteration]

Everything goes right until now. But here's how distances matrix looks like on `k=3, i=3, j=1` (I use INT_MAX as infinity):

[image]

Here we see that although shortest way is known for 3rd row, 1st column element, I can't really built path to it and show it, because it is unknown for the element right next to it. So building of the path fails and I can't show it until the next node resolves itself.

How do I find these missing paths and display them once all elements are known? I guess I need some loop which will trigger if there were known path lengths with `j` less than current and display all paths until `j-1` (thankfully `i` is known and, as I think, shouldn't change). Am I right?

P.S. I write it on C++ and can provide my implementation if you want. I think it's not necessary for the moment of writing as it's general algorithm question and doesn't belong specifically to C++ (and also my implementation smells). Thank you.

Comment: I think this would be better suited for the Computer Science stackexchange than here as you are asking an algorithm problem and not an actual implementation question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but I'll try to address it here. I believe you'd like to know how to contruct the path at any time during the floyd-warshall algorithm. Calling such path finding algorithm only makes sense after you finish computing the matrix for a given `k`. Then `Path(u, v)` would be the minimum path between `u` and `v` using as intermediary vertices only those smaller than or equal to `k`. If you try to call it when a given `k` loop hasn't yet finished running, the algorithm would return a path that doesn't consider all the improvements of using vertex `k` as an intermediary vertex. It is quite confusing to imagine which path it'd return, but it would only consider `k` as an intermediary vertex for the paths betweehn the pairs `i` and `j` you have already computed in this loop.

More information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction

Comment: So I should check for paths only between iterations (at the moment of `k` increment), and not during an iteration? That makes sense.

Comment: That seems more resonable to me. Keep in mind you'd only be checking paths that use as intermediary vertices only those up to `k`.

Comment: Perfect. I also made `j` to decrement, so that shorter paths show up first, it looks more logical. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you make `j` decrement, shorther paths won't show up first. You'll only be changing the order you consider the pairs `i, j`.